# ERROR | package org.json does not exist (import org.json.*) in eclipese

Tags: java, json, eclipse, jar

When I try to import `import org.json.JSONObject;` there is no problem. But when I run my code;

I got this errors:

server.java:7: error: package org.json does not exist
import org.json.JSONObject;
^
server.java:6: error: package org.json does not exist
import org.json.*;
^

error: cannot find symbol
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
^

I know I have to import json-20131018.jar jar file and I did.

[edited build path and libraries as following]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDA03.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnDgl.png)

and here my files order if you need
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFOnD.png)

all errors:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUccX.png

Comment: It reads like importing `org.json.JSONObject` is, in fact, a problem. Are you ignoring messages in the Problems View? Can you show the error message on-screen?

Comment: @nitind I added whole screen

Comment: Those messages don't look like they come from Eclipse. What are you doing when you get those messages - it looks like it needs class paths configured in that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.